# How to use item info interactions on my Sencha Touch Chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-charts

I have a chart with the following code

```
{
                            xtype: 'chart',
                            centered: true,
                            height: '100%',
                            id: 'ClipsViewedChart',
                            width: '100%',
                            modal: false,
                            colors: [
                                '#24ad9a',
                                '#7c7474',
                                '#a66111'
                            ],
                            store: 'ClipsViewed',
                            axes: [
                                {
                                    type: 'category',
                                    fields: [
                                        'meta_id'
                                    ],
                                    grid: true,
                                    label: {
                                        rotate: {
                                            degrees: 0
                                        },
                                        font: '10px'
                                    },
                                    title: 'Clips'
                                },
                                {
                                    type: 'numeric',
                                    fields: [
                                        'viewed',
                                        'glances'
                                    ],
                                    grid: true,
                                    position: 'left',
                                    title: 'Amount'
                                }
                            ],
                            series: [
                                {
                                    type: 'bar',
                                    label: {
                                        display: 'outside',
                                        field: 'title',
                                        orientation: 'vertical',
                                        'text-anchor': 'middle',
                                        font: '10px'
                                    },
                                    style: {
                                        minGapWidth: 1,
                                        minBarWidth: 60,
                                        maxBarWidth: 70,
                                        opacity: 0.80
                                    },
                                    labelField: 'title',
                                    xField: 'meta_id',
                                    yField: [
                                        'viewed',
                                        'glances'
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            interactions: [
                                {
                                    type: 'panzoom'
                                },
                                {
                                    type: 'iteminfo'
                                }
                            ],
                            legend: {
                                xtype: 'legend'
                            }
                        }
```

I need to add an ontap item interaction to my chart, however I am not sure how to do that, I need to show series data on tap of one of the series in my chart

This is my model code

```
Ext.define('QvidiApp.model.ClipsViews', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

requires: [
    'Ext.data.Field'
],

config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'meta_id'
        },
        {
            name: 'title'
        },
        {
            name: 'viewed'
        },
        {
            name: 'glances'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

So far I have added this to my chart

```
onItemInfoShow: function(iteminfo, item, panel, eOpts) {
        panel.update(item.get('meta_id') + '<br />' + item.get('title'));
}
```

I just want to know how to correctly render this information on my chart, the information being the title and its meta_id